# How to make the text in an SWT Link widget selectable

Tags: java, hyperlink, swt

I have a text in the [Link SWT widget](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FLink.html) created as follow:

```
Link message = new Link(parent, SWT.WRAP);
message.setText(myMessage);
```

I want the text (in `myMessage` variable) be selectable, to grant users to copy it.
How can I do this?

I have used Link widget because I need hyperlinks in the text to be clickable.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. i If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Comment: What's the purpose of this widget is beyond my understanding...

Answer (score 3):

The SWT `Link` widget is not selectable. To work around this I can think of either

1. provide a context menu for the `Link` with a *Copy* menu item that copies the text to the clipboard
2. place a *Copy* (tool) button next to the `Link` that copies the text to the clipboard
3. use a `Browser` widget which is selectable but harder to layout and requires extra work to trigger the functinality when the link is selected
4. if you don't mind the extra dependency to `org.eclipse.ui.forms`, use the `FormText`. The `FormText` can show hyperlinks and allows to select and copy text

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a StyledText to allow text selection ?

```
String string = "This is sample text with a link and some other link here.";
final StyledText styledText = new StyledText (shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER);
styledText.setText(string);

String link1 = "link";
String link2 = "here";
StyleRange style = new StyleRange();
style.underline = true;
style.underlineStyle = SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK;

int[] ranges = {string.indexOf(link1), link1.length(), string.indexOf(link2), link2.length()}; 
StyleRange[] styles = {style, style};
styledText.setStyleRanges(ranges, styles);

styledText.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        // It is up to the application to determine when and how a link should be activated.
        // In this snippet links are activated on mouse down when the control key is held down 
        if ((event.stateMask & SWT.MOD1) != 0) {
            try {
                int offset = styledText.getOffsetAtLocation(new Point (event.x, event.y));
                StyleRange style = styledText.getStyleRangeAtOffset(offset);
                if (style != null && style.underline && style.underlineStyle == SWT.UNDERLINE_LINK) {
                    System.out.println("Click on a Link");
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // no character under event.x, event.y
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Full example [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet356.java)